Fisher scoring algorithm did not converge error when running meta-analysis code in R
I am trying to run the code:
specificity_logit <- metaprop(df$TN, df$TN + df$FP, comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE,
     sm="PLOGIT", method.ci= "CP", studlab = df$Id, byvar = df$g)

But I am getting the message:

Error in (function (yi, vi, sei, weights, ai, bi, ci, di, n1i, n2i, x1i,  :
Fisher scoring algorithm did not converge. See 'help(rma)' for possible remedies.

However, when I run the same code for sensitivity it works. This code works without the part byvar = df$g, but I would like to keep it in.
